# R with plumberAPI as web service

Tags: java, r, apache-spark

I want to host a service which performs multiple analysis based on API calls. Options I researched were ApacheSpark, R with PlumberAPI, Morpheus Core and bunch of others.

Apache Spark suits the based considering features I am looking for with Big data handling but SparkContext and session takes lot of time to come online on API call.

I am considering R in production as analytics (compute) engine as web service with PlumberAPI. But I come across lot of articles mentioning R is good for analysis but not for suitable in Production. Considering setting up a server with the needed package, right versions for packages and R, monitoring as concerns for production.

I am new to R to understand the deployment of API and performance. Is it foolish to even consider R for such use case? Or are there any better options that I should consider (based on Java)?

Comment: Do I need Rstudio to run plumber? Also, I am coming across R being single threaded. If I expose R script as service will R be able to execute multiple API calls at once?

Comment: No, and read the docs. They show how to handle lots of incoming sessions

Comment: In case it helps: https://shiny.rstudio.com/deploy/ I deployed several R applications   (in the cloud) using shiny.

Comment: I've been told as well that R is not good for production due to performance issues which is more or less true because some R applications do not use all cores, however this can be solved by using the parallel package, see an example here http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/

Comment: [This](https://opensource.t-mobile.com/blog/posts/r-tensorflow-api/) might be of interest. (You'll need to scroll down to the plumber link)

Comment: @ismirsehregal Wow that was what I needed. To get some confidence on my design. This really validates my design on the production scale. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: You can also consider implementing the API via some Java framework and call your R code via FastR (R engine running on JVM, https://medium.com/graalvm/faster-r-with-fastr-4b8db0e0dceb)